# Silverlight Label doesn't want to show exact rounded value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I pass to a xaml codebehing a rounded value Round.Math(value,2) which gives for example 30.8 (in Visual Studio Watch)

and just set label1.Content to this value (Double type) and it shows instead 30.7999

why ?

Answer (score 1):

It actually does round. Displaying the number like this:

```
label1.Content = String.Format("{0:0.0}", value);
```

Should fix the issue.

Comment: Sure I can use Format but my point is I shouldn't need to use it since it's already been rounded :)

Comment: I prefer ToString because what if my format changes, it will impact this class also.

Answer (score 0):

So one has to use .ToString otherwise it doesn't round, weird.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, 2.7999... is rounded (it is actually the same thing as 2.8). If you don't like it this way you might want to use decimal instead of double.